# bootstrap ngbDatePicker how to programmatically set a date

Tags: angular, bootstrap-datepicker

We are using ngbDatePicker in our application. Due to other user actions, we need to **programmatically** set the date in the calendar to not only show the new month, but specifically highlight the DAY we want to select.

NavigateTo only sets the year and month.

I thoroughly reviewed the documentation; closest I've found is the open() function, which is supposed to set it to the current ngModel value - couldn't get this to work.

Answer (score 9):

```
//using Template Drive From
    <ngb-datepicker #dp [(ngModel)]="myDate"></ngb-datepicker>

    myDate={year:2018,month:3,day:28}

//using Reactive Form
   <form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <ngb-datepicker #dp formControlName="myDate"></ngb-datepicker>
  </form>

  this.myForm=this.fb.group({
    myDate:[{year:2018,month:3,day:28}]
  })
```